# Active MQ vs default ESB Message Store

Tags: wso2-esb

Can somebody would tell me the essential difference between the Active MQ and default ESB Message Store(s).

What would be the best use of each, simple sample case would be appriciated?

Thanks
Brano

Comment: From http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3.1/amq_persistence/FuseMBPersistIntro.html: *"ActiveMQ reduces the risk of message loss by using a persistent message store by default. Persistent messages are written to the persistent store when they are sent. The messages persist in the store until their delivery is confirmed. This means that, in the case of a system failure, ActiveMQ can recover all of the undelivered messages at the time of the failure."*

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following articles for detailed descriptions on ESB In Memory Message Store  [1] and JMS Message Store [2]. JMS Message Store can be configured to store messages in ActiveMQ as in [3]

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/In+Memory+Message+Store

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/JMS+Message+Store

[3] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of message stores that WSO2 ESB supports the 
In memory message store and JMS message store

Here are the main differences between those two

**In memory message store**

- Stores messages in an in-memory queue.
- Not persistent
- Supports random access
- Retains message order

**JMS message store**

- Stores message in a JMS queue (works with any JMS/JNDI compliant
  broker)
- Persistent
- Does not support random access
- Retains message order

So as a JMS message store you can use any JMS Broker you desire (after some configuration though). It can be Apache Active MQ , some JBOSS destribution or WSO2 message broker (another WSO2 product)

For the simple use case you asked, Please refer [this blog post by hiranya jayathilake](http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/01/wso2-esb-tips-tricks-08-message-stores.html)
It clearly define the usage of each message stores

If you are looking for some implementation refer the following posts in WSO2 Oxygen tank

1. [Implementing Store and Forward Messaging Patterns With WSO2ESB Part
   1](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/10/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-1)
2. [Implementing Store and Forward Messaging Patterns with WSO2 ESB Part
   2](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2)

Thank you